# How to pass a value from one method to another method?

Tags: c#

I'm a new to C#, please give me some advice on my program. How to pass a value from a method to another method? I am trying to do a calculation by using the value `n` from `part_number` in another method.

```c#
    class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
    
                int n;
                part_number(out n);
    
                Athlete myobj = new Athlete();
    
                int n1 = 0;
                for (n1 = 0; n1 < n; ++n1)
                {
                    Write("Enter your participant name >> ");
                    myobj.participant_Name = ReadLine();
    
                    WriteLine("Event codes are:");
                    WriteLine("T Tennis");
                    WriteLine("B Badminton");
                    WriteLine("S Swimming");
                    WriteLine("R Running");
                    WriteLine("O Other");
    
                    Write("Enter event code>> ");
                    myobj.event_Code0 = ReadLine();
    
                }
    
                double totalCost;
                const double cost = 30.00;
                totalCost = cost * n1;
    
                WriteLine("The total cost is {0}", totalCost);
    
    
                static void part_number(out int n)
                {
                    n = 0;
                    WriteLine("Enter the number the participant this year>> ");
                    n = System.Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
    
                    while (n >= 40)
                    {
                        WriteLine("Please enter number between 0 to 40");
                        n = System.Convert.ToInt32(ReadLine());
                    }
                }
            }
```

How to pass the value of `n` from `part_number` method and another method? I need to the use that value to do a calculation in another method. Should I build a class for it?

Thank you!

Comment: Just declare the new method with a parameter, exactly in the same way you've already done with `part_number`. Then when calling it, pass it: `NewMethod(n);`, for example, with the declaration being `static void NewMethod(int n)`.

Comment: Don't forget to create an answer for the next person

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would simply add an argument to the method such as:

```
void MyOtherMethod(int number)
{
    // do something with number
}
```

If you wanted, you could pass multiple things by commad delimiting them:

```
void MyOtherMethod(int number, string name)
{

}
```

You can also have a method returning a value:

```
int MyReturningMethod(int number)
{
    return number + 2;
}
```

The possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call your other method and pass it in.

```
public static Main(string[] args)
{

  PartNumer(out var partNumber);

  OtherMethod(partNumber);

}

static void PartNumber(out int pn)
{
   pn =1;
}

static void OtherMehtod(int partNumber)
{
   Console.WriteLine($"Your part number is {partNumber}");
}
```